# Determine the return value type of a function inside itself

Tags: c++, decltype

To the best of my knowledge, the C++ core language currently does not provide a general functionality to determine the return value type of a function inside of itself, such as:

```
auto f(std::uint8_t value)
{
    double result {0.0};
    // ...
    auto&& tmp = static_cast<decltype(return)>(value);
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Why does a feature like `decltype(return)` not yet exist? Would it be justified to have the wish that it be added to the core language?

Comment: Consider for example if you were to `return tmp` instead, then there would be recursion in the type resolution process. Implementing something like what you have in mind sounds nightmarish at best.

Comment: If the question is specifically combining `decltype(return)` with `auto`, this would be a huge can of worms to deal with all the cases where it can become really hard for the compiler to figure it out. Simple example: `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(return), int>)` now has to check the entire function to know which branch to take while discarding the untaken branch, but taking one branch over the other could change the return type. Yes, you could say that  case is ill-formed. That's among the simplest of many bad cases you have to deal with. At best, it slows down the compiler.

Comment: "*Why does a feature like `decltype(return)` not yet exist?*" - because there has never been a need for it. "*Would it be justified to have the wish that it be added to the core language?*" - you can wish all you want, but it won't happen unless someone proposes it to the committee, justifies it, gets it approved, and vendors actually implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `result`, so the type that `auto` will deduce (*at **compile time***) is the type of `result`.

As suggested in the comment, the type deduced by `auto` is not the same as the one that `decltype(result)` would deduce, in general, as they behave differently: `auto` uses [template type deducion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), whereas `decltype` does [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype). Therefore they can differ in the reference-ness of the deduced type, which can be quite important.

In your example, however, since `result` is an *unparenthesized id-expression*, `decltype(result)` will deduce just `double`, and the return `auto` will deduce the same, so probably this is fine. You decide.

```cpp
auto f(std::uint8_t value)
{
    double result {0.0};
    // lots of code ..
    auto&& tmp = static_cast<decltype(result)>(value);
    // lots of code ...
    return result;
}
```

Once the program is compiled, the return type of `f` ***is*** the type of `result`, and this cannot change whatsoever, therefore there's no need to have the syntax support `decltype(return)`.

The point is that regardless of the complexity of the case you consider, **once you are able to compile the program**, that means that **the compiler is able to determine all the types it needs**. It can be hard for humans to find out what the return type is (and many other template things, honestly), but not for compilers. Or, better, it's not hard nor easy for the compiler to deduce the types: it either does (and then you can run the program) or it doesn't (and it fails at compile time).

Comment: What you say works in this simple code sample but imagine a situation where typing decltype(result) is not possible, i try to give a better example.

Comment: @DanielF, it can be other than clear to _you_ and _me_, but it is crystal clear to the compiler. If it is not clear to the compiler, the compiler will just fail to compile. In other words, once the compilation is completed, the return type of `f` is know, written somewhere in the executable, and it is immutable.

Comment: `auto` and `decltype` has different deduction rules.

Comment: @PasserBy, you're right. I ignored that beacuse I don't think it is the point of the question. However, I have changed it. Do you think it is a bit better now?

Answer (score 2):

Enrico's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884246/2079303) shows how to do what you need.

To answer the question:

> Why does a feature like decltype(return) does not yet exist?

Either because such feature hasn't been proposed, or because such proposal hasn't been accepted into the language.